# Accessing grails app on koding virtual maching

Tags: grails, groovy, virtual-machine, koding

i would really appreciate help on this.

I have grails 2.3.2 and groovy installed on my koding virtual machine. Whenever i try to run my grails application on the VM, the server starts successfully and the console says `" Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/TrekIsis" TrekIsis being my application name.`

In my environment i have configured a url to my virtual machine as http://trek.ishan0205.kd.io but whenever i hit "http://trek.ishan0205.kd.io:8080/TrekIsis" it says "http://trek.ishan0205.kd.io:8080/TrekIsis  cannot be served at this time. Wrong domain/server configuration?" though when i go to "http://trek.ishan0205.kd.io" i get kodings default virtual machine welcome message meaning that the path to the server is configured correctly.

I would really appreciate if you can guide me on how i can access my grails application on the virtual machine and set the right configuration.

PS: more information on koding : https://koding.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it. Whenever we run grails for development we use the embedded tomcat to run the application but once the application is run on test environment or production environment then because of performance concerns  the grails app is added to a container and then deployed rather than using the run-app or run-war command.

So all i had to do was make a war of my application, add it to the webapps of my container and it worked like a charm.

Hope this helps someone stuck like me.